# MATLAB for loops for different data names

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have 12 data files (one for each month called FlowData_JAN.dat-FlowData_DEC.dat

Ive written a code to plot a graph for one month, but i am struggling to write them into a for loop that will subplot each month on one figgure. because when im using n = 1:12 but my data files arent numbered theyre words?

```
load('FlowData_MAY.dat', 'FlowData_JUN.dat','FlowData_JUL.dat', 'FlowData_AUG.dat', 'FlowData_SEP.dat', 'FlowData_OCT.dat', 'FlowData_NOV.dat','FlowData_DEC.dat', 'FlowData_JAN.dat', 'FlowData_FEB.dat', 'FlowData_MAR.dat','FlowData_APR.dat') ; format long

[N1:N12] = ('FlowData_JAN.dat','FlowData_FEB.dat', 'FlowData_MAR.dat','FlowData_APR.dat','FlowData_MAY.dat', 'FlowData_JUN.dat','FlowData_JUL.dat', 'FlowData_AUG.dat', 'FlowData_SEP.dat', 'FlowData_OCT.dat', 'FlowData_NOV.dat','FlowData_DEC.dat');

for n = 1:12
    subplot(4,3,n);
    % add this earlier datafile = fopen('Nn');
    datafile = fopen('Nn');
    D = textscan(datafile, '%D %D %f'); 
    %Assing variables to data
    dt = ((datenum(D{1}))-5600) ; %Date Convert to numbers
    tt = (datenum(timeofday(D{2}))); %Time

    yall= (D{3}); %height of water 
    yy = yall([1:24], :);
    xall = ((dt+tt)*24); %date and time added, so that all one variable-in hours
    xx = xall([1:24], :);
    %need to plot yy against xx

   %period
   k = 12.5;

   %Calculate number of data points
   NN = length(xx);
   %Calculate Design Matrix
   phi = [ones(NN,1),sin(k*xx), cos(k*xx), sin(2*k*xx), cos(2*k*xx)];
   %Solve System equations
   aa= phi\yy;
   %Calculate fitted values of y
   yfit = phi*aa;
   %Plot the output
   plot(xx, yy, 'rx', xx, yfit, 'k-');
   pause (0.5); %or hold on?

end
```

Please help! My error is clearly in how ive assigned my data files to be called N1 to N12 but i dont know what else to do!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`[N1:N12] = ...` is not a valid Matlab syntax. You can e.g. store file names in a cell array instead (note curly brackets):

```
fileNames = {'FlowData_JAN.dat','FlowData_FEB.dat', 'FlowData_MAR.dat','FlowData_APR.dat','FlowData_MAY.dat', 'FlowData_JUN.dat','FlowData_JUL.dat', 'FlowData_AUG.dat', 'FlowData_SEP.dat', 'FlowData_OCT.dat', 'FlowData_NOV.dat','FlowData_DEC.dat'};
for n = 1:12
    % ....
    datafile = fopen(fileNames{n});
    % ....
end
```